# Asking a collaborator to work on a second problem he is already working on

Tags: etiquette, collaboration

I am a PhD student in Mathematics and I'm working in collaboration with a more experienced researcher for some time. We are working in a nice topic in which some good results are being attained. On the other hand, there is another problem in the field in which I'm very interested in, and which seems to be very important. I became aware recently that he's also working in that problem and recently published a first paper on it. In particular he looks to be interested in several open questions related to such problem.

My question here is: is it fine for me to ask if it would be OK to collaborate with him in that other problem as well (I would like to keep both, since on the one hand the one we are working right now is going well, and since the other one looks to be very promising)? If so, how would be the best way of doing so?

I mean, my issue is that this is something that he's already doing, and in particular the particular paper he just published was with some other people. I fear it would be rude to ask to get involved in something that has already began without my participation, but perhaps this is just because I'm quite an introvert individual and always worry what people are going to think of whatever I say.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it would be fine to ask, assuming that you have something to contribute. Tell him of your interest and what your thought are on that problem. Then, depending on his reaction, you can make a request to participate.

Just make sure you have something to add to a research project.

Don't use introversion as an excuse not to make your wishes known. While it may not feel especially natural to you, practice will change that. I once made the mistake of not speaking up for my own interests and it cost me dearly.